# Cannot Close Android App - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, audio-streaming

I have created an android app with react native which plays Radio using this module.

https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-android-audio-streaming-aac

I have used the following code in my function,

```
AACStreamingAndroid.setURLStreaming(channel);
AACStreamingAndroid.play();
```

I cannot close the app once I start the radio and stop it.The app continues to stay in background.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "continues to stay in background"? Does it keep playing?

Comment: Every player should have a stop right ? ..call this  AACStreamingAndroid.stop() on onBackPressed() or on onDestroy()..

Comment: @MikeM. The streaming stops but the app icon stays at the system tray event after I exit the app

Comment: @sunilsunny The Player stops but the app continues to stay in the mobile tray

Comment: Mobile tray means ? recent apps list right ? if yes it is supposed to behave like that .Please see other apps ,all will have this same behavior.

Comment: @sunilsunny No,not the recent apps list.I am telling about the notification top down slide.The app closes only when I force stop it.

Comment: Ah .Ok then cancel the notification manager on exit of the app.How are you setting this Lockscreen or Background player..?

Comment: Ok I checked the link you have given.. There is method called "destroyNotification" on that code calling that should destroy the notification manager as well.Call that on onDestroy.

Comment: @sunilsunny Can you help me on how to do that? I am new to react-native

Comment: Sry for the late answer :  

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
AACStreamingAndroid.destroyNotification()
   super.onDestroy();

 }
Use this on your main activity..

Comment: Thank you. It worked :-)